# How to reshape a list created by web scraping?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, reshape

I hacked together the code below.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pandas import DataFrame
import itertools
import numpy as np

url_base = "https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t="

tckr = ['MSFT','AAPL','AMZN']
        
i = 1

url_list = [(s, url_base + s) for s in tckr]
data_list = []

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:76.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/76.0'}

for t, url in url_list:
    print(i)
    i = i + 1
    print(t, url)
    print('Scrapping ticker {}...'.format(t))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')
    #writer.writerow([t])
    for row in soup.select('.snapshot-table2 tr'):
        data_list.append([td.text for td in row.select('td')])

df = DataFrame(data_list)
```

So, the final dataframe is shaped as 36,12; it contains 3 shapes that are each 12,12. I guess something is happening in the following line of code, and I don't totally understand it.

```
data_list.append([td.text for td in row.select('td')])
```

Now, my data looks like this.

[image]

Somehow, I would like to get 72 columns of data per ticker, so the final result looks like this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store all the sublists of data per ticker into it's own list.  Instead of blending them all.  Then you can use `itertools` `chain.from_iterable` to make one large list per ticket, take every even item as a key and odd item as as values in a dictionary, and put the final dict for each ticker into a larger list.  That can turn into a dataframe.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pandas import DataFrame
import itertools
import numpy as np
from itertools import chain

url_base = "https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t="

tckr = ['MSFT','AAPL','AMZN']
        
i = 1

url_list = [(s, url_base + s) for s in tckr]
data_list = []

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:76.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/76.0'}

for t, url in url_list:
    print(i)
    i = i + 1
    print(t, url)
    print('Scrapping ticker {}...'.format(t))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')
    #writer.writerow([t])
    l = []
    for row in soup.select('.snapshot-table2 tr'):
        l.append([td.text for td in row.select('td')])
        x = list(chain.from_iterable(l))
        d = dict(zip(x[::2], x[1::2]))
        d['Index'] = t
        
    data_list.append(d)

df = DataFrame(data_list)
```